# How to get data from google sheet to website

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I want to get data from sheet to my website.
I have a google sheet which contain water data w.r.t humidity and temperature
Sheet:-[This is the sheet from where I want to get data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbivD.png)

In this sheet,
In column "A" Temperature is written and in row "1" humidity is written,
And water value is written at a particular temperature and humidity

As when the temperature is 2 and humidity is 5% then the water data is 0.24.

I want to create a web page in which user can enter the temperature and humidity and get the water data on web page which is present in google sheet.

like when the user enter temperature 5 and humidity 5%, then they will get output 0.32 (which is already present in the sheet)

Can anyone please help me to get this data.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the google sheets API, [https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#:~:text=The%20Google%20Sheets%20API%20is,Update%20spreadsheet%20formatting](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#:%7E:text=The%20Google%20Sheets%20API%20is,Update%20spreadsheet%20formatting)

This is their "quick start" example:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js